# How to persist and save value from shared prefernces in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to persist value after user leaves page, also I would like to persist selected values, so I found out shared prefernces and I save it locally, but when I left page and return it remains unselected.

So I decided to convert my multipleSelected list to String, because sharedprefernces can't save list of ints and sfter that save selected values in lists. So how can i solve that problem when user leaves page and selected items become unselected.

```
class DataBaseUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataBaseUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DataBaseUser> createState() => _DataBaseUserState();
}

class _DataBaseUserState extends State<DataBaseUser> {
  int index = 1;

  /// add selected items from list
  List multipleSelected = [];

  /// another list to form the new list above previous one
  List chosenListsAbove = [];
  List basesNames = [];
  SharedPreferences? sharedPreferences;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Typographys.primaryColor,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size(125, 125),
        child: AppBarService(),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //  chosenOne(),
          Card(
            color: Typographys.gradientCard2,
            child: ExpansionTile(
              iconColor: Colors.white,
              maintainState: true,
              title: Text(
                'Bases',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'fonts/Montserrat',
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 35),
              ),
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                getDataBaseList(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 22,
                ),
                getUpdateBaseButtons(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getDataBaseList() {
    return FutureBuilder<List>(
      future: BasesService().GetBases(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List? baseNames = snapshot.data;
        print(baseNames);
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: baseNames?.length ?? 0,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            Future<void> _onCategorySelected(bool selected, id) async {
              final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              if (selected == true) {
                setState(() {
                  multipleSelected.add(id);
                  List<String> stringsList =
                      multipleSelected.map((i) => i.toString()).toList();
                  // store your string list in shared prefs
                  pref.setStringList("stringList", stringsList);
                  List<String> mList =
                      (pref.getStringList('stringList') ?? <String>[]);
                  print('HERE');
                  print(mList);
                  print('HERE 2');
                });
              } else {
                setState(
                  () {
                    multipleSelected.remove(id);
                  },
                );
              }
            }

            return Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                    title: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.0),
                      child: Text(
                        baseNames?[i]['name'] ?? 'not loading',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'fonts/Montserrat',
                            fontSize: 24,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    leading: Checkbox(
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                      checkColor: Colors.green,
                      side: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.white),
                      value: multipleSelected.contains(
                        baseNames?[i]['id'],
                      ),
                      onChanged: (bool? selected) {
                        _onCategorySelected(selected!, baseNames?[i]['id']);
                      },
                    )
                    //you can use checkboxlistTile too
                    ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget getUpdateBaseButtons() {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FutureBuilder<bool>(
              future: BasesService().SelectBaseAsync(multipleSelected.cast()),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (snapshot.data == true) {
                      BasesService().SelectBaseAsync(multipleSelected.cast());
                      print(multipleSelected.cast());
                      print(multipleSelected);
                      successSnackBar();
                    } else {
                      notSuccessSnackBar();
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Send bases',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'fonts/Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 22,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        letterSpacing: 2),
                  ),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: Size(200, 40),
                    primary: Colors.green,
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
                return Container();
              })
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you simplify widget by removing `BasesService`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh hi, no, I am retriving from this service names of bases

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correclty, cant you just save items in `WillPopScope` like

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => SaveMyPreferences,
  child: const Scaffold(

    body: Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      size: 50.0,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If your data that you want to save comes from the API and is constantly updated (as it was in my case), then you do not need to use the `shared preference` package. This package will not help you. In my case, in order to save the checkboxes selected by the user and after reloading the page to show him which items in the list were selected (I use checkboxes), I write to a file on the device and then read the saved data from this file. So you are going to need `path_provider` package and `dart:io` and these two functions

to write from function where you choose items

```
_onCategorySelected(bool selected, id) async {
                final Directory directory =
                    await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                if (selected == true) {
                  multipleSelected.add(id);
                } else {
                  multipleSelected.remove(id);
                }
                final File file = File('${directory.path}/my_file.json');
                file.writeAsStringSync('{"selected": $multipleSelected}');
                setState(() {});
              }
```

to read from file:

```
 Future<String> read() async {
          String text = '';
          try {
            final Directory directory =
                await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            final File file = File('${directory.path}/my_file.json');
            text = await file.readAsString();
            print('HELLO');
            multipleSelected = json.decode(text)["selected"];
          } catch (e) {
            print("Couldn't read file");
          }
          return text;
        
        }
```

and before the `listview.builder` comes, you need to use `read()` function ro read the saved values from file.

It is not the greatest solution (maybe, the worst one), but if you haven't got enough time and you don't have any state management and you just need to solve issue right now, it can be really helpfull.